# null cannot be cast to non-null

Tags: android, kotlin

Getting this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null
> type java.lang.String
> at com.example.newsorgapi.MainActivity$onCreateOptionsMenu$1.onQueryTextChange

at line:

```
if(it.description.lowercase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(searchtext))

 override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {

        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menuitems, menu)

        val item = menu.findItem(R.id.search)
        val searchView: SearchView? = item?.actionView as? SearchView
        searchView?.setOnQueryTextListener(object: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                return true
            }

            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {

                tempnene.clear()

                val searchtext = newText?.lowercase(Locale.getDefault())
                if(searchtext!!.isNotEmpty()){

                    tempne.forEach {

                        if(it.description.lowercase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(searchtext)){

                            tempnene.add(it)
                        }
                    }
                    binding.recycler.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
                else{

                    tempnene.clear()
                    tempnene.addAll(tempne)
                    binding.recycler.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }


                return true
            }


        })

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the variables in your chain of functions there requires a String, but you're passing a null in.  That's illegal in Kotlin, String can not be null.  Either you need to not pass in null, you need to change the parameter it takes to be String? (a nullbale String), or you need to force non-nullness.  That an be done by doing either `value!!` (which will force an immediate NPE if it's null), or doing `value ?: default` where default is some default value (probably "").

Most likely the problem is `val searchtext = newText?.lowercase(Locale.getDefault())` is making it a String? because null is returned if newText is null.  An alternative to that is `newText?.lowercase(Locale.getDefault()) ?: ""`  That will make it return "" if newText is null instead of null.